# Kotlin for assertThat(foo, instanceOf(Bar.class))

Tags: junit, kotlin

How would you write `assertThat(foo, instanceOf(Bar.class))` with Kotlin?

Seems that it does not like the `.class`

I would like to go for an assertion which is a bit more "precise" than just an `assertTrue(foo is Bar)` if possible

Comment: AssertJ is btw a nice fluent api for assertions. It would be written like this: `assertThat(foo).isInstanceOf(Bar::class.java)`. The big advantage is, that you must not know all the components like `instanceof()` by hard, because the code completion of the fluent-api lists you all possibilities.

Comment: @guenhter If you have several hundred tests with hamcrest you are not interested in an AssertJ being slightly better (maybe). Also the problem is not about how fluent the test is or how good code completion is. It's about Kotlins quirky class handling.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Bar::class` returns instance of [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html), which is Kotlin equivalent of Java's [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

`instanceOf` method requires `Class` instance, not `KClass`, so you have to convert it using `Bar::class.java`.

So your assertion should be like:

```
assertThat(foo, instanceOf(Bar::class.java))
```

More info about Java interop you can find [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html).

Also you can have a look at [Hamkrest](https://github.com/npryce/hamkrest) library which may add more fluency to your assertions:

```
assert.that(foo, isA<Bar>())
```

Comment: That's not completely true: `Bar.class` isn't allowed in kotlin. It is `Bar::class` what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the Hamkrest link

Comment: Finally someone who gave the correct answer instead of suggesting alternative tools.

Answer (score 6):

Since Kotlin 1.5 you can also do this with the assertions of Kotlin, withtout using JUnit. This is prettier than the example posted in the question.

Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Assertion example:

```
import kotlin.test.assertIs

assertIs<Bar>(foo)
```

Answer (score 4):

`assertThat(foo, instanceOf(Bar::class.java))`

Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass

Comment: Too bad there ain't an assertIs(foo, Bar) function :/ Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Atrium (https://atriumlib.org) and write the following

```
assertThat(foo).isA<Bar>{}
```

And in case you want to assert more about foo, say Bar has a `val baz: Int`, then you can write the following

```
assertThat(foo).isA<Bar> { 
  property(subject::baz).isSmallerThan(41) 
}
```

Comment: Already committed to Kotlin and Hamcrest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assertInstanceOf` [doc here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertInstanceOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object))

And it become as simple as :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertInstanceOf

assertInstanceOf(Bar::class.java, foo)
```

Comment: Already committed to Kotlin and Hamcrest.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to go for an assertion which is a bit more "precise" than just an assertTrue(foo is Bar) if possible

This is a code smell in the making.

The (ridiculously named) "Liskov substitution principle" of good software design recommends not depending on a concrete implementation: a subtype should always be able to replace a type with the client code using it not caring / being affected.

If you are depending on some special functionality of the subtype, use the subtype after `is`.

If the subtype is dynamic (anonymous class?) or the name of the type is not in the namespace of the test code (private / internal class?), and/or you need to assert a base class instance was provided, assert something about the functionality of the subtype that the supertype does not provide (or vice versa).

If there is no such functionality that has a publicly observable effect, then reflect on what you are really trying to test.

The main exception I see is when

> assert something about the functionality of the subtype that the supertype does not provide (or vice versa).

would be extremely slow or otherwise difficult to run (e.g., messes up state).